# Insert multiple row on multiple column with sqlite3 on Node js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm try to insert multiple row on multiple column with sqlite in node js, for example:

```
 INSERT INTO data(key) VALUES (?),(?),(?)
```

So, in this example i have insert 3 value (namespaces) inside a column, after this query i have 3 row in my database.

I want insert multiple value, inside two column. Example of query:

```
INSERT INTO data(key, sales) VALUES ((?),(?),(?)), ((?),(?),(?))
```

I have try a lot of solution, like the above. But of course, it doesn't work.

There is a way to do this?

Node Package: "sqlite3": "^4.0.6",

Comment: Which `npm` package you are using?

Comment: this is my package: "sqlite3": "^4.0.6",

Answer (score 0):

```
var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem ('column1', 'column2') VALUES ('value1', 'value2'), ('value1', 'value2')");
```

Comment: i receive: SQLITE_ERROR: row value misused

Comment: Do you have the same number of columns and data you are trying to save?

Comment: Yes! CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(key string, sales string), INSERT INTO data ('key', 'sales') VALUES (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))

Comment: Just remove outer brackets.

Comment: Now i retrive this: SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range

Comment: Should be `column1` or `"column1"`, not `'column1'`. The latter is a string, not a column name.